# How do you push git worktrees to a remote branch

Tags: git, git-worktree

I don't know if I have a fundamental misundertanding about what a worktree is or what, but, I have tried fixing some bugs on a worktree. Used the `git worktree add` command to make it. I navigated to the folder it created, made my changes, made a commit, and now I am ready to push to the commit to a remote branch so I can create a Pull Request.

This is my workflow when doing good old fashioned git branches. I will:

1. create a local branch
2. make changes
3. stage changes
4. commit staged changes
5. Push and set upstream branch
6. Create a PR

With my worktree I am stuck on step 5.

1. create worktree `git worktree add <path>`
2. make changes
3. stage changes
4. commit staged changes
5. Push and set upstream branch
6. Refspec error

When I try to push with `--set-upstream` I get the `src refspec <branch> does not match any` error. I then looked for the .git folder to find that there wasnt one, just a .git file with the path to that worktree.

There are a lot of tutorials out there on worktrees, and every one I have tried to read/watch has skipped this crucial detail. They tend to just cover the add/remove commands.

Is a worktree even considered a branch? I didnt think so at first but `git branch` now shows me as being on a branch with the name of my worktree, interstingly, and unexpectedly it also shows that branch as being under another branch I was working on as if it were a sub branch of some kind

```
$ git branch
+ 371601_TLS_Certificates
* 395275_396239_MVPbugs
  aspire-dev-shell-baseurl
  ls
+ main
  users/rrhughes/US/371601_TLS_Certificates
  users/rrhughes/US/383751_resolve_URL
  users/rrhughes/US/383751_settings_NXupdate
  users/rrhughes/US/383751_settingsui
  users/rrhughes/US/settings_devops
```

Later via brute force attempting to find a solution I tried a bare `git push` and git told me it was not tracking a remote branch (as expected). It then provided me with this command

```
git push --set-upstream origin <my branch name>
```

I copy pasted it and it worked. However, this is nearly identical to the command I was trying before, and the command that I use to set upstream from regular git branches. the only difference was the name of my branch. It is a standardization on my dev team to make remote branches under a file structure for easy navigation and organization, so my command usually looks like this.

```
git push --set-upstream origin users/username/bugs/<my branch name>
```

Updated Question(s): So I am still confused why this did not work. Do I need to name my local worktree exactly what I will name it in the remote? If I want to name my local branch something simple, how do I set it to track a remote with a different name that meets my teams remote branch naming standard?

-Original Question: how do I get these changes on this worktree into my remote repo so I can create a PR?-

Comment: Could you integrate the update into your main writeup? It's best not to call attention to edits here.

Comment: "I don't know if I have a fundamental misundertanding about what a worktree is" It seems to me you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a _branch_ is, at least with regard to pushing one. Being surprised that you cannot say bare `git push` suggests that, anyway.

Comment: "Is a worktree even considered a branch?" In a very real sense, yes, absolutely. The whole point of a worktree is that it lets you have two branches checked out simultaneously, the one in the main project folder and the one in the worktree folder. It's like a version of your project dedicated to one branch. Isn't that why you made the worktree in the first place?

Comment: @matt “In a very real sense, yes, absolutely.”—In my opinion you are conflating usage with “being”. I could be content to work all the time on ”detached head” similar to how other people work on branches, but I wouldn’t call it a _kind of_ branch simply because I use it in a similar way.

Comment: @matt I think you misunderstood me. I am not, nor was  I ever surprised I couldn't do  a bare git push.

Comment: if you have no local branch named `users/username/bugs/<my branch name>`, then `git push origin users/username/bugs/<my branch name>` will not work. If you want to push to a remote branch with a different name, use the explicit syntax: `git push origin <local>:<remote>`. For example: `git push origin <my branch name>:users/username/bugs/<my branch name>`. This is what I meant with "feel free to adapt the above command" in my answer

Comment: @LeGEC, this got me part of the way there, how do I set the other branch up as the tracked remote branch? Do I have to explicitly type that every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `--set-upstream` with a [refspec](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec):

```
git checkout -b branch-name
# Assuming remote is `origin`
git push --set-upstream origin branch-name:users/rrhughes/US/branch-name
```

Or using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76020604/1725151) shortcut as LeGEC suggested for pushing the
currently checked out branch:

```
git push -u origin $(git branch --show-current):users/rrhughes/US/$(git branch --show-current)
```

Now the easiest thing to do if you’re using git-pull(1) is to use `git pull origin` while you are checked out on that branch:

```
$ git pull origin
Already up to date.
```

Because note that the following will *not* work as you probably
intend/expect:

```
$ git pull origin branch-name
fatal: couldn't find remote ref branch-name
```

### Elaboration on why git-worktrees(1) is irrelevant

Switch to a new worktree and create branch
`users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme` (note the `git worktree` command):

```
$ git worktree add ../demo -b users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme
Preparing worktree (new branch 'users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme')
HEAD is now at a1e8606 init
$ cd ../demo
$ # Assumes `origin` exists already
$ git push -u origin users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme
Password for 'https://LemmingAvalanche@github.com':
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote:
remote: Create a pull request for 'users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme' on GitHub by visiting:
remote:      https://github.com/LemmingAvalanche/test-worktree/pull/new/users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme
remote:
To https://github.com/LemmingAvalanche/test-worktree.git
 * [new branch]      users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme -> users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme
branch 'users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme' set up to track 'origin/users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme'.
```

This worked.

(See section “Annex: git-worktrees/remote demonstration” for a full
script that you can try on your machine.)

What branch am I on?

```
$ # We’re in the `demo` worktree
$ pwd
/home/kristoffer/programming/demo
$ git branch
+ main
* users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme
```

`*` is the currently checked out branch. What’s the `+` in front of
`main`?

According to `man git-branch`:[1]

> Any branches checked out in linked worktrees will be highlighted in
> cyan and marked with a plus sign.

So what happens if I change back to the directory I was in before I
changed directory into the worktree?

```
$ cd -
/home/kristoffer/programming/test-worktree
$ git branch
* main
+ users/kristoffer/demo/update-readme
```

Makes sense:

- `main` is the checked-out branch since this is the branch that this
  worktree is on
- The branch in the *other* worktree (`demo`) is marked with `+` (the
  mark for a branch checked out in another worktree)

#### What is a worktree?

First you need to understand what a “working tree” is:[2]

> The tree of actual checked out files.

A “worktree” is a *working tree* plus repository metadata, with the
repository metadata mostly “shared among other worktrees of a single
repository”[3] [4].

Also:

> A repository can have zero (i.e. bare repository) or one or more
> worktrees attached to it.

When you did `git init`, you made a repository with one worktree. When you did `git worktree add` you created the second worktree (more on this in the section “Back to basics (init)”).

#### Is a worktree even considered a branch?

No, and these things have nothing to do with each other.

A branch was created for you with the base name of the worktree since
you gave:

```
$ git worktree add ../some-name
Preparing worktree (new branch 'some-name')
HEAD is now at a1e8606 init
```

I.e. you didn’t provide the optional `commit-ish` after the branch:[5]

```
$ # Assuming that `branch-name` exists
$ git worktree add ../some-name branch-name
```

#### Unpacking “push git worktrees to a remote branch”

When you push a branch to a remote repository, you are pushing a ref. A
ref doesn’t care what your working tree looks like (e.g it could be
“dirty” but that doesn’t affect the ref). In fact a remote repository is
likely to be “bare”, which means that it doesn’t have a working tree.

So the sentence by itself does not make sense.

But what was clearly meant was:

> Push the branch that is checked out in this work tree

Which *does* make sense if you are using something like `git push`
without explicitly giving the branch name, since then you want whatever
branch is checked out to be pushed.

Then the standard troubleshooting applies:

- Am I on the branch that I think I’m on?
- Is the branch tracking a remote?
- Have I pushed the branch to the remote?
- Does my config (`git config`) allow me to say `git push origin` (note: no branch)?

#### Back to basics (init)

Given this blank slate:

```
mkdir a-new-start
cd a-new-start
git init
```

What’s the worktree and branch in this case?

The exact same principles apply since a non-bare repository like this
one has one worktree, i.e. the one where you are right now; this is the
“main worktree”.[6] If you started using `git worktree add` then you would
be creating “linked worktrees”.[6]

So then we can ask ourselves again:

- Am I on the branch that I think I’m on?
- Is the branch tracking a remote?
- Have I pushed the branch to the remote?
- Does my config (`git config`) allow me to say `git push origin`?

And these questions turn out to be much more elementary since the
worktree is in fact mostly a distraction from the real problem.

#### Notes

1. On `git version 2.40.0`
2. `man gitglossary`, entry “working tree”
3. `man gitglossary`, entry “worktree”
4. The non-shared metadata “are maintained separately per worktree
   (e.g. the index, HEAD […]” (ibid)
5. From `man git worktree`, under subcommand `add`:

   > If `<commit-ish>` is omitted and neither `-b` nor `-B` nor `--detach` used,
   > then, as a convenience, the new worktree is associated with a
   > branch (call it `<branch>`) named after `$(basename <path>)`.
6. `man git worktree`

#### Annex: branches/worktrees/remote demonstration

This shell script demonstrates how branches, worktrees, and remotes can
interact:

```
# Make a `temp` directory in your home directory (but change to
# e.g. `/tmp` if you prefer)
cd
mkdir -p temp
cd ~/temp/
mkdir demo
cd demo
mkdir local-repo
mkdir remote-repo
cd remote-repo
git init --bare
cd ../local-repo
git init
# Make an initial commit so that Git won’t freak out when
# we try to make the next branch for the worktree
git commit --allow-empty --message=Init
git remote add origin ../remote-repo
# Make the branch `worktree-branch` and check it out
# in `worktree`
git worktree add ../worktree -b worktree-branch
git push --set-upstream origin worktree-branch:users/rrhughes/US/worktree-branch
git worktree list
cd ..
mkdir local-repo-2
cd local-repo-2
git init
git remote add origin ../remote-repo
# This will fetch the branch as `users/rrhughes/US/worktree-branch`;
# we didn’t give an explicit refspec and this is the name that we gave it
# on the remote
git fetch origin
# Now you should get a message that the branch is set
# up to track the remote branch of that name
git checkout users/rrhughes/US/worktree-branch
# Make a commit for the remote
git commit --allow-empty --message='Second commit'
git push origin users/rrhughes/US/worktree-branch
# Back to the worktree where `worktree-branch` is set up
cd ../worktree
# This should update the branch in this worktree with the
# second commit
git pull --ff-only origin
```

Comment: "And these questions turn out to be much more elementary since the worktree is in fact mostly a distraction from the real problem." Exactly so. But this is precisely what I meant by my comments which you critiqued.

Comment: I do hope hunter11 is not your real password to GitHub or anything else.

Comment: Oh shoot..… :·)

Comment: @matt If someone thinks that worktrees and branches are the same then I don’t think it’s helpful to say that they are (“in a real sense”). I guess you were going for the “they’re the same in practice” approach? Chalk it up to different answering styles. ;)

Comment: I would like to accept this answer, as it gave me a lot of good information. However in your very first example you detailed my exact steps that aren't working, then told me it works. I have tried this again and again. Git will only let me `--set-upstream`  branches with the EXACT name of my local branch. Why tracking a different name works for you, and not for me I don't know, but that is my problem and I still haven't resolved it

Answer (score 2):

There is a little gotcha with `git branch --set-upstream <ref name>` : it works only with *existing* ref names. It won't work if the remote branch hasn't already been created.

So you would need to first `push` (with an explicit remote branch name) to create the remote branch, then set `git branch --set-upstream`. Actually `git push --set-upstream ...` will do that in one go.

---

I found it cumbersome to have to manually type my local branch name on first push, so I use the following alias:

```
git config --global alias.pushnew \
    '! git push -u origin $(git branch --show-current)'
```

and just type: `git pushnew`

If your workflow requires a different naming pattern (e.g: your local branches are called `<name>` and should match a remote branch named `user/<username>/<name>`), feel free to adapt the above command.

---

also: no, this issue has nothing to do with worktrees.

Comment: I just alias `git push origin @`. Seems simpler. I never actually want an upstream so I don't say `-u`.